# Split string to dictionary as key,list

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a string type which will return thousands of records in the format

`key1,val1,val2,val3,val4,val5:key2,val6,val7,val8,val9,val10:key3,val11,val12,val13,val14,val15`

I want to assign this to a dictionary as Key,List so it looks like

key1,[val1,val2,val3,val4,val5]

key2,[val6,val7,val8,val9,val10]

key3,[val11,val12,val13,val14,val15]

.
.
.

All keys are unique in the string and the List size is constant for all records.

At the moment I'm using Split and looping each record using

```
    //short example string - may contain 1000's
    string newstr = @"key1,val1,val2,val3,val4,val5:key2,val6,val7,val8,val9,val10:key3,val11,val12,val13,val14,val15";

    Dictionary<string, List<string>> mydictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    foreach (string item in newstr.Split(':'))
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>(item.Split(','));
        mydictionary.Add(list[0], list);        
    }
```

My question is, is there a more efficient/quicker way of doing this for 1000's of records using C#4.0 rather than looping?

**UPDATE:** having tested the various answers the following are the 'correct' times

[image]

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.IO.StreamReader myFile =  new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\ooo\Desktop\temp.txt");
    string newstr = myFile.ReadToEnd();
    myFile.Close();

    TimeSpan ts;
    TimeSpan te;
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();


    ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> mydictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    foreach (string item in newstr.Split(':'))
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>(item.Split(','));
        mydictionary.Add(list[0], list);
    }
    te = stopWatch.Elapsed;
    Console.WriteLine("MyTime: " + (te - ts).ToString());



    ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
    var result = newstr.Split(':')
         .Select(line => line.Split(','))
         .ToDictionary(bits => bits[0],
                       bits => bits.Skip(1).ToList());
    te = stopWatch.Elapsed;
    Console.WriteLine("JonSkeet: " + (te - ts).ToString());


    ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
    string[] keysAndValues = newstr.Split(':');
    var newdictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>(keysAndValues.Length);
    foreach (string item in keysAndValues)
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>(item.Split(','));
        newdictionary.Add(list[0], list);
    }
    te = stopWatch.Elapsed;
    Console.WriteLine("Joe: " + (te - ts).ToString());


    Console.WriteLine("Records: " + mydictionary.Count.ToString());


    stopWatch.Stop();
}
```

Comment: Does your values actually comes in a string? Or is there any "streaming" of the values?

Comment: The looping will have to happen, and often writing it yourself is the fastest.

Comment: By the look of it, your current code includes the key in the list of items - is this correct/a problem?

Comment: They come in a string in the format shown as one large string. Yes the string also includes the unique keys.

Comment: Is there a performance bottleneck in your current implementation? Unless you preprocess the data, you are always going to have to split the string as you have done, whether using RegEx or LINQ or regular string manipulation.

Comment: @DaveR. - it's actually quite fast and not a bottleneck but I always try and avoid loops if there is a quicker alternative. Perhaps there isn't.

Comment: @Rawling - the items do also contain the key. It's not a problem in this case.

Comment: @ooo my answer is comparing your code vs LINQ, there is no point in adding me into your benchmark as your just re-testing your own code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is potentially faster, as the Dictionary is constructed with the required capacity to avoid reallocations:

```
//short example string - may contain 1000's     
string newstr = ...;

string[] keysAndValues = newstr.Split(':');
var mydictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>(keysAndValues.Length);
foreach (string item in keysAndValues)     
{         
    List<string> list = new List<string>(item.Split(','));         
    mydictionary.Add(list[0], list);
    // remove key from list to match Jon Skeet's implementation
    list.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Less readable than Jon Skeet's LINQ version though.

Comment: Apologies Joe, I was doing you a disservice there. I've updated the timings in my original post based on the correct file being imported and processed.

Comment: Probably you can go *slightly* *slighly* faster, by changing the list initialization. i.e. initialize the list with the correct capacity then add the items of the array with `for(int i=1; commaSplits.Length; i++) ...`. `RemoveAt(0)` is very inefficient in `List<T>` ...

Comment: @digEmAll, in fact the `List<T>` constructor that takes and `IEnumerable<T>` is smart enough to check for an `ICollection<T>` and if so initialize to the required capacity.  So this won't make any difference.  RemoveAt(0) is reasonably efficient in this case: it copies the internal array, but does no reallocation.

Comment: @Joe: an inner copy can take some time if the inner list is long, so I pointed out since that overhead can be easily avoided. However, we're talking about crumbs of seconds here...

Comment: @digEmAll, OK, I see what you mean now, and also why you said "slightly slightly".

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
var result = text.Split(':')
                 .Select(line => line.Split(','))
                 .ToDictionary(bits => bits[0],
                               bits => bits.Skip(1).ToList());
```

It may well not be any more *efficient*, of course... have you measured that it needs to be? If you're only doing this for "thousands" of records, I'd expect it to be done in the blink of an eye. Furthermore, I'd expect any IO (network, disk) to be the bottleneck before this code is.

From your comment:

> it's actually quite fast and not a bottleneck but I always try and avoid loops if there is a quicker alternative

Don't do that. Aim for the *simplest* code which does the job, then check whether it performs *well enough*. Personally I prefer my LINQ-based code, but your existing code is fine too. Any faster alternative is likely to end up being significantly harder to write, read and maintain. Why would you go to that effort if the benefit is insignificant?

Note that my code *doesn't* have the key as the first value in the list - it matches the specification, but not your sample code.

Comment: Neater, yes. But is it "more efficient/quicker" ?

Comment: You miss a closing bracket after `Split(',')`

Comment: @Jon - thanks for this. I'll measure the speed and report back :)

Answer (score 2):

Running the code you posted against a LINQ solution (like @JonSkeet's) shows that LINQ takes roughly double the time your current approach does for over 1000 records.

Therefore to answer your question:

> is there a more efficient/quicker way of doing this for 1000's of records using C#4.0 rather than looping?

I would say no.

Benchmark test code:

```
 var value = "key{0},val1,val2,val3,val4,val5:";
 string newstr = "";
 for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
 {
     newstr += String.Format(value, i + 1);
 }

 var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
 sw.Start();
 Dictionary<string, List<string>> mydictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
 foreach (string item in newstr.Split(':'))
 {
     List<string> list = new List<string>(item.Split(','));
     mydictionary.Add(list[0], list);
 }
 sw.Stop();
 Console.WriteLine("Looping time: " + sw.Elapsed.ToString());
 sw.Reset();
 sw.Start();
 var result = newstr.Split(':')
                    .Select(line => line.Split(','))
                    .ToDictionary(bits => bits[0],
                                  bits => bits.Skip(1).ToList());
 sw.Stop();
 Console.WriteLine("LINQ time: " + sw.Elapsed.ToString());
 Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: This isn't correct. LINQ statements aren't evaluated until they are queried - all you've done is setup the query here, not enumerated the result. Also, there are no colons splitting up the key/value list pairs.

Comment: @DaveR. +1 your spot on, I wasn't evaluating the LINQ query (or splitting the data with `:`!). I have updated my answer.

Comment: @DaveR.: that is not correct. `ToDictionary()` performs an immediate evaluation, there's no need of `ToList()`

Comment: @digEmAll in fact, your right. I wasn't sure first time around as I was simply taking Jon Skeet's answer but according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb738017#todict) it does do an immediate evaluation. I have removed the call to `ToList`.

Comment: Many apologies about the lazy evaluation mix-up. I misread the query and @digEmAll is absolutely correct.